# android app runs out of screen on real device

Tags: screen, android-sdk-2.3

I am new to android application development. i have made an applications which runs fit on simulator screen but when i run it on real device it creates problem, app does not fit on android it goes out of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Really need more information(code example of layout)....

Maybe the emulator screen resolution is bigger than the device....

Make sure you are using DIP (device independent pixel) measurements.....

Comment: code: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <VideoView android:id="@+id/viewvideo" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></VideoView>
</LinearLayout>